# How does Linux kernel dynamically use a module?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules, dynamic-linking, dynamic-loading

Understanding the Linux Kernel says

> The kernel has two key tasks to perform in managing modules. The first task is mak-
>   ing sure the rest of the kernel can reach the module’s global symbols, such as the
>   entry point to its main function. A module must also know the addresses of symbols
>   in the kernel and in other modules. Thus, **references are resolved once and for all
>   when a module is linked.** The second task consists of keeping track of the use of
>   modules, so that no module is unloaded while another module or another part of the
>   kernel is using it. A simple reference count keeps track of each module’s usage.

Is it correct that any shared library can be both dynamically linked (using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`), and dynamically loaded (by `dlopen()`, `dlsym()` and `dlclose()`)?

Is a module a shared library to the Linux kernel?

How does Linux kernel dynamically use a module? Is it by dynamic linking (using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`), or dynamic loading (by `dlopen()`, `dlsym()` and `dlclose()`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it correct that any shared library can be both dynamically linked (using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`), and dynamically loaded (by `dlopen()`, `dlsym()` and `dlclose()`)?

Yes. The difference is that dynamic linking is driven by the dynamic linker, and by the time the program starts (from the program author’s perspective), the libraries have been linked and all the symbols have been resolved; dynamic loading involves doing all that manually.

> Is a module a shared library to the Linux kernel?

More or less, but the loading mechanisms are different. The dynamic linker, and `libdl`, are user-space only, they can’t be used in the kernel.

> How does Linux kernel dynamically use a module? Is it by dynamically linking (using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`), or dynamical loading (by `dlopen()`, `dlsym()` and `dlclose()`)?

The kernel loads modules using [`load_module`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18.14/source/kernel/module.c#L3656), which does all the work itself: loading the ELF object, mapping the required segments, performing all the relocations, etc. It also performs a few module-specific tasks: checking their license, hooking them into `sysfs`, calling their initialisation function...

`load_module` is accessed from user space using [the `init_module` or `finit_module` system calls](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/init_module.2.html).

Comment: Thanks. (1) Is libdl the library which provides dlopen(), dlsym() and dlclose()? (2) Do the three do the same or similar work, dynamic linking, dynamic loading (dlopen(), dlsym() and dlclose()), and load_module ?

Comment: 1. Yes, `libdl` is the library which provides `dlopen()` etc. (See [`dlopen(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) which mentions `-ldl`.) 2. They perform similar work, at least in terms of processing relocations, which is the core of dynamic linking. As mentioned `load_module` does a fair amount more, relating to module-specific functionality.

Comment: Thanks. Does dlopen() perform the work of dynamic linking, besides dynamic loading? If yes, does it perform the similar work of dynamic linking and static loading? Why do we need to call dlsym() after dlopen() in order to use a function defined in the shared library, instead of using the function directly just like when dynamic linking and static loading?

Comment: `dlopen()` performs full-blown dynamic linking on the loaded object and any dependencies; but it doesn’t rewrite GOT entries in the load*ing* object, because there aren’t any — otherwise the library would be loaded by the dynamic linker. This also explains why you need to use `dlsym()`. What do you mean by static loading?

Comment: Thanks. "static loading" is opposed to dynamic loading, and if I am correct, static loading means that  loading the shared library at the time loading the executable which uses the shared library. Why "doesn’t rewrite GOT entries in the loading object, because there aren’t any" means "need to use dlsym()"?

Comment: Oh, OK; I’ve never seen that referred to as “static loading”, it’s “dynamic linking”. Dynamic linking works by filling in addresses for symbols in place-holders (the GOT entries); it can only do so if the place-holders exist, and the compiler only adds place-holders for symbols it can resolve (to some extent) at build-time. If you want to `dlopen` a library, you typically don’t want to resolve it at build-time, so there is no place-holder; that means you need to deal with the addresses and calls yourself, using `dlsym()`.

Comment: Does dlopen() only perform loading not linking? If that is correct, is that the reason why I have to explicitly use dlsym()? For static loading, see https://www.quora.com/Systems-Programming/What-is-the-exact-difference-between-dynamic-loading-and-dynamic-linking/answer/Jeff-Darcy

Comment: Does dlsym() manually perform linking?

Comment: I also appreciate if you can take a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/476083/what-kinds-of-files-can-be-dynamically-loaded

Comment: Thanks for the static loading reference. Linking happens as a result of `dlopen`, either immediately or when functions are called, depending on whether lazy binding is enabled. `dlsym` only performs symbol lookup.

Comment: Thanks. "dlopen doesn’t rewrite GOT entries in the loading object", and where does dlopen write/record the linking result? "dlsym only performs symbol lookup" , and what does dlsym look up?

Comment: `dlopen` records linking results in the load*ed* object. Think of program A loading library B, with `dlopen`, and library B requiring library C; `dlopen` will link B and C, updating the GOT entries in B to point to the required symbols from C. `dlopen` doesn’t perform any linking from A (the loading object) to B. `dlsym` looks up the symbol it’s given: its signature is `dlsym(handle, symbol)` — it looks up `symbol`, and if it finds it, returns its address.

Comment: Thanks. (1) does dlsym look up some symbol used in A and defined in B?  does dlsym look up some table stored somewhere for that purpose?  (2) Does dlsym look up some symbol used in B and defined in C? I guess no, because the linking has done that and stored the result in the GOT of B? (3) If program A requires library B, and B doesn't require any library, then does dlopen not perform any linking?

Comment: 1. `dlsym` looks in the table of exported symbols, stored in B. 2. No, `dlopen` does that when it loads B (and C). 3. Yes.